# Assign CSS To A <div> Element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am wanting to add CSS to a DIV element so I can align it to the right and have a form directly to the left of it. I am working on making a hacked version of 2048. My HTML code is:

```
    <div id="completetwentyfourtyeightgame" align="right">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="heading">
                <div class="scores-container">
                    <div class="score-container">0</div>
                    <div class="best-container">0</div>
                </div>
                <div class="above-game">
                    <a class="restart-button">New Game</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="game-container">
                <div class="game-message">
                    <p></p>
                    <div class="lower">
                        <a class="keep-playing-button">Keep going</a>
                        <a class="retry-button">Try again</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="grid-container">
                    <div class="grid-row">
                        <div class="grid-cell"></div>
                        <div class="grid-cell"></div>
                        <div class="grid-cell"></div>
                        <div class="grid-cell"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid-row">
                        <div class="grid-cell"></div>
                        <div class="grid-cell"></div>
                        <div class="grid-cell"></div>
                        <div class="grid-cell"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid-row">
                        <div class="grid-cell"></div>
                        <div class="grid-cell"></div>
                        <div class="grid-cell"></div>
                        <div class="grid-cell"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid-row">
                        <div class="grid-cell"></div>
                        <div class="grid-cell"></div>
                        <div class="grid-cell"></div>
                        <div class="grid-cell"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tile-container"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

        <div align="left">
        <form id="inputs">
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>Tile Value 1</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <input type="text" id="tilevalueone" value="2">
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Tile Value 2</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <input type="text" id="tilevaluetwo" value="4">
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Starting Score</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <input type="text" id="score" value="0">
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Tile Value To Win</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <input type="text" id="winpoints" value="2048">
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
```

My css is:

```
.completetwentyfourtyeightgame{
position: absolute;
right: 0px;
}
```

What is wrong with the code? Is it in my HTML or in my CSS? Here is a screenshot of what the code is doing:

Instead of the table being directly on the left and the game on the right, the table stays below the game.
[After changing the . to a # in the css, this happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdDiN.png)

I am not wanting the game to be on the edge if the website and the table to be right next to the left border of the game. Also, is there a way to make javascript reload the game to apply the values without reloading the page itself?

Comment: We have no idea what's wrong with it, you haven't told us what problems you're having with it; what's not working? What's happening instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be:

`#completetwentyfourtyeightgame`in your CSS.

You have it as `.completetwentyfourtyeightgame`

This is because with a `.` starting it, that is for denoting a new CSS class. To target something with an `id` - as you have it declared in your HTML - you need to use a `#`

Answer (score 1):

```
#completetwentyfourtyeightgame{
  float: right;
}
```

`#` = id selector
`.` = class selector

i think `float` is a better usage here than `position: absolute`. you typically want to stay away from absolute positioning if you can

```css
#completetwentyfourtyeightgame{
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="completetwentyfourtyeightgame" align="right">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="heading">
            <div class="scores-container">
                <div class="score-container">0</div>
                <div class="best-container">0</div>
            </div>
            <div class="above-game">
                <a class="restart-button">New Game</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="game-container">
            <div class="game-message">
                <p></p>
                <div class="lower">
                    <a class="keep-playing-button">Keep going</a>
                    <a class="retry-button">Try again</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-container">
                <div class="grid-row">
                    <div class="grid-cell"></div>
                    <div class="grid-cell"></div>
                    <div class="grid-cell"></div>
                    <div class="grid-cell"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="grid-row">
                    <div class="grid-cell"></div>
                    <div class="grid-cell"></div>
                    <div class="grid-cell"></div>
                    <div class="grid-cell"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="grid-row">
                    <div class="grid-cell"></div>
                    <div class="grid-cell"></div>
                    <div class="grid-cell"></div>
                    <div class="grid-cell"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="grid-row">
                    <div class="grid-cell"></div>
                    <div class="grid-cell"></div>
                    <div class="grid-cell"></div>
                    <div class="grid-cell"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tile-container"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <div align="left">
    <form id="inputs">
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>Tile Value 1</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <input type="text" id="tilevalueone" value="2">
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Tile Value 2</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <input type="text" id="tilevaluetwo" value="4">
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Starting Score</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <input type="text" id="score" value="0">
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Tile Value To Win</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <input type="text" id="winpoints" value="2048">
                </th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: doing float: right and position: absolute does the same thing

Comment: @JamesEstes in this situation you are correct. however, what if you have two elements you want positioned to the right one after the other? if you float them both, then they'll "see" each other and wont overlap, but if you position absolute them both, they'll overlap, or you'll need to find out the widths and offset it with a left/right position as well.

Comment: @JamesEstes, also, floats care about paddings and margins of their parents, absolutes do not. here's an example https://jsfiddle.net/v7vowm0m/